# Flip Base64 Image before send to API with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web app with OCR reading from ID Card. But the device front camera is not mirror as normal because of hardware problem. OCR engine can't read the image properly. How to flip image base64 (flip from right to left) before send to API.

[image]

Comment: Use `gl-react`: https://github.com/gre/gl-react-image/issues/22#issuecomment-472145433

Comment: Render the image to a `<canvas>` and then flip every pixel. After this, re-encode the image. Base64 on an image seems a bit strange, but that would be your last step if your API requires it.